# findViewByID() не видит ID

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Всем привет,
читаю книгу Head First android dev. и в одном из первых заданий у меня вылетает ошибка, уже сто раз перечитал и перепроверил, всё вроде правильно, а всё равно функция не видит id и выдаёт ошибку. Просьба помочь, тем кто разбирается

.strings

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Beer Adviser</string>
    <string name="find_beer">Find Beer!</string>
    <string name="brands"></string>
    <string name="hello">Hello</string>

    <string name="tryp" />
    <string-array name="beer_colors">
         <item>light</item>
         <item>amber</item>
         <item>brown</item>
         <item>dark</item>
     </string-array>
</resources>
```

.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:text="@string/brands"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
    />
```

.java

```
public void onClickFindBeer(View view) {
    TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
    Spinner color = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.color);
    String beerType = String.valueOf(color.getSelectedItem());
    brands.setText(beerType);
}
```

Вторая строка .java файла : findViewById(R.id.brands) подчёркивает "brands" красным и не даёт скомпилировать код, хотя в .xml файле brands стоит и никаких ошибок не выдаёт. Подскажите кто знает, как решить эту проблему
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы путаете ID строки и ID элемента разметки.

У вас в разметке для `TextView` указан ID `textView`. Именно по нему и надо искать `View` в разметке методом `findViewById(@IdRes int id)`

Т.е. вам надо так:

```
TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Вы же сейчас пытаетесь найти текстовое поле по ID строки в ресурсах

Comment: Спасибо большое, только начал в этом разбираться, возможно в книге опечатка или я что то недопонял, но теперь всё работает

Answer (score 3):

У вас `brands` это строка из `strings.xml`. Вы ее указываете как `id`, хотя он у вас `textView`, а не `brands`

Comment: спасибо за помощь